# RE to match just strings not starting with value="

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to code a regular expression to capture a pattern that doesnt starts with the string '`value="`'. Already tested with negative lookaheads, but unsucessfull. Wondered if it is even possible with RE... any help is welcome.

The expression is `^(?!value=")([M|A|S|R]+\d+[M|S|A|R|a|b|c|d|e|f|x|\d|\s]+)\b`

```
start

this value this should be captured 
 "M533x539S18520507x461S18528469x461S2e00c512x486S2e014467x487S2fc04492x528"

but this last one not 
 value="M519x515S11520482x485S26506504x500"

end
```

https://regex101.com/r/ugARR0/1

```
<div style=" height:100%" contenteditable="true"  name="target_0_div" cols="40" rows="3" tabindex="100" class="translation-editor form-control teste" id="id_eedbdc1996c09949_0" lang="sgn-BR" dir="ltr" abc="3" maxlength="100"> M533x539S18520507x461S18528469x461S2e00c512x486S2e014467x487S2fc04492x528 </div>

<input type="hidden" id="target_0" name="target_0" value="M533x539S18520507x461S18528469x461S2e00c512x486S2e014467x487S2fc04492x528">

<script>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cVWlQp/5

thanks

Comment: You may match `value="[^"]*"` pattern and capture the other one and only grab the captures, `value="[^"]*"|\b([MASR]+\d+[MSARabcdefx\d\s]+)\b`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w53Mmt/1).

Comment: made some progress using negative lookbehind (?<!value=")([M|A|S|R]+\d+[M|S|A|R|a|b|c|d|e|f|x|\d|\s]+)\b but still captures the second string partially

Comment: ***"...to capture a pattern"*** - Which pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a bit:

```
^"[MASR]+[\d]+[MSAa-fx\d]+"
```

https://regex101.com/r/cVWlQp/2

Since you're starting from the beginning of the string using `^`, you can ignore a string that begins with something other than your quoted value.

If you're trying to grab the value inside the quotation marks, you can just wrap that section in parens:

```
^"([MASR]+[\d]+[MSAa-fx\d]+)"
```

---

After your question was updated...

If you are trying to match the string inside of HTML content without grabbing values that are in an HTML attribute, you could simply use:

```
[\s|>]+([MASR]+[\d]+[MSAa-fx\d]+)
```

This regex looks for the match to start with a closing `>` or whitespace and returns the string in the first "group".

https://regex101.com/r/GNbWfK/1

Comment: You can remove the square brackets around `[\d]+`

Comment: but the problem is that I dont want to grab values that come after the value=" string

Comment: The answer will be different now that you've added an HTML example to your question.

Comment: sorry about that.. tryed to simplify

Comment: @RonnieFagundesdeBrito I added another simple regex to match on content within HTML tags. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a JavaScript environment that supports lookbehinds you can do it like this:

```
(?<!value=")(?<=")([MASR]+[\d]+[MSAa-fx\d]+)(?=")
```

Surprisingly, many current browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) this feature (notable exception: Firefox) and node.js as well.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZK8i1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You might use a negative lookbehind, but it is not yet widely supported.

```
(?<!value=")\b[MASR]+\d+[MSAabcdefx\d]+\b
```

- `(?<!value=")` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `value="`
- `\b[MASR]+\d+` Word boundary, match any char of MASR and 1+ digits
- `[MSAabcdefx\d]+\b` Match 1+ times any of the character class followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tzQV1A/1)

But as you are using html, another option is to use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)  and use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get for example the innerText:

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
let html = `<div style=" height:100%" contenteditable="true"  name="target_0_div" cols="40" rows="3" tabindex="100" class="translation-editor form-control teste" id="id_eedbdc1996c09949_0" lang="sgn-BR" dir="ltr" abc="3" maxlength="100"> M533x539S18520507x461S18528469x461S2e00c512x486S2e014467x487S2fc04492x528 </div>

<input type="hidden" id="target_0" name="target_0" value="M533x539S18520507x461S18528469x461S2e00c512x486S2e014467x487S2fc04492x528">`;

let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll(".translation-editor.form-control.teste")
  .forEach(x => console.log(x.innerText.trim()));
```

Comment: I am limited to a regex hotspot!

Comment: @RonnieFagundesdeBrito Did the initial pattern work?